# How to create Magento 2 theme?

Tags: magento2, theme

I have given tasks in Magento to create a custom theme. My task is to create Magento Theme from scratch. I want a source that I can refer to. If anyone did this before please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you can easily checking it in Magento 2 Documentation is there chapter about it https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html – every single step is described with file structure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this cover it in detail [link](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-create-magento-2-theme.html)

And this is one of the best videos covering this topic [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdS2ppmpBxs)

This might be useful for you- [link](https://github.com/mcspronko/magento-2-pronko-consulting-theme)

Answer (score 0):

You need to below require steps for creating a new theme in the Magento 2:-

1. Create a directory for the theme under **app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>**

**Example**: `app/design/frontend/Custom/Default`

2. Add a declaration file theme.xml and optionally create etc directory and create a file named view.xml to the theme directory

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Custom Magento Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
    <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media> 
</theme>
```

3. Add a composer.json file (Optional)

```
{
     "name": "custom/theme-frontend-default",
     "description": "N/A",
     "config": {
         "sort-packages": true
     },
     "require": {
         "php": "~7.2.0||~7.3.0||~7.4.0",
         "magento/framework": "*",
         "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "*"
     },
     "type": "magento2-theme",
     "license": [
         "OSL-3.0",
         "AFL-3.0"
     ],
     "autoload": {
         "files": [
             "registration.php"
         ]
     }
 }
```

4. Add registration.php

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
    ComponentRegistrar::register(
        ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
        'frontend/Custom/Default',
        __DIR__
    );
```

5. Add preview image following path: `app/design/frontend/Custom/Default/media/preview.jpg`
6. Create directories for CSS, JavaScript, images, and fonts here: `app/design/frontend/Custom/Default/web`
7. Configure your theme in the Admin panel and activate the new theme

   Admin panel > Content > Design > Configuration > Select theme and Edit >
   Default Theme >  Applied Theme > Select "Custom Magento Theme" from the
   dropdown > Save Configuration

   **Screenshot**: [https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/19172983?key=22fab33dc5226af2ee39586a53effa28][1]
8. Clear cache.

   Now you can see your **Custom Magento Theme** is installed and activated.

I hope this is useful.

Thank you :)
[1]: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/19172983?key=22fab33dc5226af2ee39586a53effa28

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this link for the Magento front-end theme creation process
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-overview.html

Thanks.